# Single image not displaying after deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, .net-4.5

I deployed my website to http://ffinfo.azurewebsites.net/ to test it out and the log is not showing up on the deployed site. If I do a control+F5 in Visual Studio 2012 the logo will show up just fine (it should be appearing in the top left cornor). I have verfied the the logo was uploaded by going to http://ffinfo.azurewebsites.net/images/logo.png If I look at the source of the deployed site from I.E. I see the img tag

```
<img id="imgBanner" src="/Images/logo.png" alt="Final Fantasy Info.com Logo" style="height:127px;width:400px;" />
```

I have another image that works just fine using the  tag it is just this one image that is not working. I have also tryed with the tildy and it does not display

I can take the code for the image that works and past it on the line right about the broken logo code and that image will not work either. If I change the line of code for the working image so it points to the logo it works fine.

Why is it that only this one image is not showing up and only when deployed to Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this in Chrome dev tools, you have a css rule in your bundled stylesheet

```
img { display: none; }
```

Which probably doesn't help

Comment: Thanks the display code was only in the .min version of the CSS file. I guess I forgot to change it, I updated it to match the non .min version and now it displays.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the relative path to the image is not correct, check your browser debugger to see if it fails to load the resource, it should helpe if you refer your image like this: src="~/Images/logo.png"

Comment: Been debugging and don't see any issues retrieving the image but indeed the display is set to none in your css and is not overwritten.